# Render parent route first when child route is async

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to render the parent route when the child route is loaded in the background(async).

```
<Route path="/" component={Layout}>
  <Route
    path="home"
    getComponents={(a, cb) => require.ensure([], require => {
      const { default: Component } = require<{ default: any }>('./pages/home')
      cb(null, Component)
    }, 'home')} />
</Route>
```

Here, the `Layout` component is waiting for `home.js` before the first render.

**Expected behaviour**

When I go to '/home'

1. `Layout` should be rendered first
2. `home.js` should be fetched async
3. A re-render should be triggered with the `home.js` component

I'm using `react-router@3.0.0`

### Edit

I've figured out a simple solution using [react-async-component](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-async-component)

**router.jsx**

```
<Route path="/" component={Layout}>
  <Route
    path="home"
    component={Home} />
</Route>
```

**home-async.jsx**

```
import { asyncComponent } from 'react-async-component'

const Async = asyncComponent({
  resolve: () => System.import('./home.js'),
})
export default Async
```

I was able to achieve the desired behaviour with this approach. Still, I'm open for any suggestions.